# Dependency injection containers: how to handle objects that aren't a dependency of anything?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

When we use a dependency injection container, ideally we pull only a single-top level object from it (e.g. an instance of `Program`) and let the rest of the application be composed automatically by the container.

However, sometimes there are objects which are not a dependency of anything else, yet we want to have them in the object graph. For example, I could have a `Notifier` class with a `Bazinga` event, and this `BazingaConsoleLogger` class:

```
public class BazingaConsoleLogger
{
    private readonly Notifier notifier;

    public BazingaConsoleLogger(Notifier notifier)
    {
        this.notifier = notifier;
        this.notifier.Bazinga += HandleBazinga;
    }

    private void HandleBazinga(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bazinga!");
    }
}
```

Because `BazingaConsoleLogger` is not a dependency of anything, it will not be created by the dependency injection container. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: is this your actual issue or just a contrived example?

Comment: @Mauricio: my actual issue is slightly more complicated: I have two pre-existing classes which don't know each other, and I would like an event on the first class to trigger a method call on the second class. Adding a third class which imports instances of the other two seemed the natural way to achieve this, but the third class is never instantiated by the dependency injection container.

Comment: I think you generalized your question too much. It's not quite clear if you want to wire events or you really want to manage unmanaged dependencies (?). Either way, I recommend creating a question with your *actual* issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `IListener` marker interface could be added to the class. In the application start-up code, I could then pull all `IListener` instances from the container in addition to the main program instance:

```
container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IListener>>(); // just to create the listeners
var program = container.Resolve<Program>();
program.Run();
```

Another option is to use an `IStartable` interface ([inspired by Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/Startable)) which solves a more general problem, i.e. the launching of multiple services at start-up. In the case of an event listener class, the `Start` method could be used to subscribe to the event (thus removing this responsibility from the constructor) or simply do nothing. The `Program` class could be one of the `IStartable` implementations.

```
var startables = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IStartable>>();
foreach (var startable in startables)
{
    startable.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If BazingaConsoleLogger is a service and not a dependency of anything, then it's not used anywhere in your program, so the class can be deleted. Less code FTW! :-)

I don't think that's what you really mean, so can you further explain how you are currently using BazingaConsoleLogger? If you *are* in fact using BazingaConsoleLogger, you already have a dependency (explicit or not) to BazingaConsoleLogger.

EDIT: to wire events loosely I use [Windsor's Event Wiring facility](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Event-Wiring-Facility.ashx). If your container doesn't have anything like it, it shouldn't be hard to code it, [here are the general principles](http://hammett.castleproject.org/?p=115).

Comment: The desired effect is to have console output showing Bazinga events. In my example, this desired effect can be achieved simply by creating `BazingaConsoleLogger`. However, since no other class uses BazingaConsoleLogger as a dependency, the dependency injection container will never create it. In other words, the existence of a `BazingaConsoleLogger` instance is a desired feature of the composition, but this does not follow automatically by following dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

In Windsor you could hack something like this:

```
container.Register(
   Component.For<Notifier>()
      .OnCreate((kernel, notifier) => 
         notifier.Bazinga += kernel.Resolve<BazingaConsoleLogger>().HandleBazinga)
);
```

however I agree with Mauricio Scheffer and I would treat this as smell and rethink your design in this case.